# R - Solving Indeterminate Problems

Tags: r

I feel that this is a somewhat complex issue which may not necessarily have a simple solution and may require machine learning or other advanced techniques to resolve.

Firstly, to explain the issue at hand, say we have a runner who participates in a number of outdoor races where the elements (ie wind) affect the athletes speed. If we know the baseline speed of the runner it’s easy to determine the percentage affect that the elements have had in each race, for example:

```
    Name Baseline Race1 Race2 Race3
1 Runner      100   102    98   106
```

The contributing `element_factors` for Race1, Race2 and Race3 are:

```
[1] 1.02 0.98 1.06
```

In this example we can see that the runner in Race 1 has had a tail wind which has increased his baseline speed by 2%, etc.

However, in the real world we don’t necessarily know what the runners baseline speed is because all we have are their race results to go on and we don’t necessarily know how the elements are affecting the baseline.

Take for example the race results as listed in the following dataframe

```
df<-data.frame(Name = c("Runner 1","Runner 2","Runner 3","Runner 4","Runner 5"),
Baseline = c("unknown","unknown","unknown","unknown","unknown"),
Race1 = c(101,"NA",80.8,111.1,95.95),
Race2 = c(102,91.8,"NA",112.2,"NA"),
Race3 = c(95,85.5,76,"NA",90.25),
Race4 = c("NA",95.4,74.8,116.6,100.7))

      Name Baseline Race1 Race2 Race3 Race4
1 Runner 1  unknown   101   102    95    NA
2 Runner 2  unknown    NA  91.8  85.5  95.4
3 Runner 3  unknown  80.8    NA    76  74.8
4 Runner 4  unknown 111.1 112.2    NA 116.6
5 Runner 5  unknown 95.95    NA 90.25 100.7
```

What I want to be able to do is calculate (approximate) from this dataframe each runners baseline speed value and the factors relating to each race. The solutions in this case would be:

```
Baseline<-c(100,90,80,100,95)
[1] 100  90  80 100  95

element_factors<-c(1.01,1.02,0.95,1.06)
[1] 1.01 1.02 0.95 1.06
```

Setting the baseline speed as the runners average is overly simplistic as we can see that some runners only race in events that have a tail wind and therefore their baseline will fall lower than all their race results.

Comment: The table shows race speeds for each runner which differ from a theoretical baseline. The baseline and element_factors are unknown, they are what need to be calculated.

Comment: We can see from the element_factors vector I’ve provided for this scenario that some races only have a positive factor >1.00

Comment: I’m trying to back calculate (or approximate) the baseline and element_factors vector solely from race results

Comment: Sounds like you might just want to do a multiple linear regression. If the element factors are multiplicative you could just do the regression on the log of the speeds. But that's more of a stats question and less of a R question

Comment: If the baseline was known then certainly that would have been the way I would have attacked this. But I’m unsure if that’s possible when the baseline also needs to be determined?

Comment: Right. It needs to be estimated. How else are you going to do that?

Comment: I guess maybe an iterative approach could work but that would be time consuming, that’s why I thought maybe the machine learning route was the way to go. Although my experience in that field is somewhat limited so was hoping to get some confirmation from others that was the way to go before committing the time to tackling it.

Comment: Iterative? Why don't you think fitting a regression will get you what you want?

Comment: The way I'm looking at it is that for Runner 1 (Race1 = B1*α1, Race2 = B1* α2, etc) and Runner 2 (Race1 = B2*α1, Race2 = B2* α2, etc), etc. Where B1, B2 ... Bn are each runners baseline speed and α1, α2 ... αn are the `element_factors` for each race. If I approximate B1, B2, etc I'm not necessarily going to get the same α1, α2, etc for each runner where α1, α2, etc should be consistent across all runners. If that makes sense?

Comment: So i would need to iteratively run B1, B2 ... Bn to get α1, α2, etc as close as possible across each runner.

Comment: Your letting the shape of your data dictate the way you think about it too much. Imagine instead having a column for runner, a column which tells which race it was, and a column for time. Using that you can fit a single model that includes parameters for all the runners and all the races.

Comment: If I get what you are saying I create a data frame with `colnames("Runner","Race","Speed")` and then run a regressor as per follows `regressor<-lm(Speed ~ Race + Runner, data = runners)`? This methodology doesn't give the defined solutions in my query, possibly because it isn't calculating an independent baseline for each runner?